# Paypal Sandox Error 580022

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I´m using Paypal Adaptive Account gem (paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments) for a rails (4.0.2) app in my sandbox testing with the GetVerifiedStatus operation with this error:

```
 Error: [#<PayPal::SDK::AdaptiveAccounts::DataTypes::ErrorData:0x007fcd60e15bb0 
 @errorId=580022, @domain="PLATFORM", @subdomain="Application", @severity="Error", 
 @category="Application", @message="Invalid request parameter: emailAddress", 
 @parameter=[#PayPal::SDK::AdaptiveAccounts::DataTypes::ErrorParameter:0x007fcd60e15408 
 @value="emailAddress">]>]
```

The call i´m doing is:

```
@api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptiveAccounts::API.new( :device_ipaddress => "127.0.0.1" )
@get_verified_status = @api.build_get_verified_status({
    :emailAddress => usuario.mail,
    :firstName => usuario.nombre,
    :lastName => usuario.apellido1,
    :matchCriteria => "NAME" })

# Make API call & get response
@get_verified_status_response = @api.get_verified_status(@get_verified_status)
```

Since last week this app was working perfectly before my hdd says goodbye and I have to restore the backup. I think I have configured the app fine but I´m not sure. My rails app has this conf:

```
PayPal::SDK.configure(
  username: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_PASSWORD"],
  signature: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_SIGNATURE"],
  app_id: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_APP_ID"],
  http_timeout: 30,
  mode: ENV["PAYPAL_CLASSIC_MODE"]
)
```

printenv | grep PAYPAL | sort

```
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_APP_ID:           APP-80W284485P519543T
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_MAIL:             my@email.com
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_MODE:             sandbox
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_PASSWORD:         [my-sandbox-password]
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_SIGNATURE:        [api-signature]
PAYPAL_CLASSIC_USERNAME:         *****
```

Finally, I´ve to say that the same app deployed in Heroku / Paypal Sandbox (and using the same sandbox account) is working.

What I´m missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the paypal customer service:

> Error 580022 is typically returned when there is invalid values in the request. -
>   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/?mark=580022
>   From your request, I see you have:*
>
> ```
> :emailAddress => usuario.mail,
> :firstName => usuario.nombre,
> :lastName => usuario.apellido1,
> :matchCriteria => "NAME" })
> ```
>
> The message says "Invalid request parameter: emailAddress"
>
> Please verify that actual values are being sent through and let me
>   know if still having issues.

In my case, emailAddress has a white space before email. Now is working with a .squish